# Stepping over a yield statement

Tags: python, generator, pdb

When in the Python debugger (pdb) I want to step over a yield statement, but hitting (n) for next brings me to the *destination* of the yield i.e. the consumer of the generator.  I want to go to the next line that is executed within the generator.  Is there any way to do this?

I'm using Python 2.6

Comment: That definitely sounds like what next should be doing.  (From the perspective of the generator, `yield` is a function call and should be jumped over by `next`.)  This sounds like a debugger bug; you might want to see if it's been reported at http://bugs.python.org/.

Comment: Although I can see why the behaviour asked for here might be desirable, I can see an equally good argument that taking a single step in a debugger shouldn't run the risk of jumping out of the debugging loop and running indefinitely. (eg. if the generator is never called again). It sounds like a job for a breakpoint to me. (Or a new debugger command.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make yield work in debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380092/how-to-make-yield-work-in-debug-mode)

Answer (score -2):

If your debugger allows you to use breakpoints and change variable values when you're there, it's as simple as [in pseudo code]

```
Set Boolean yieldValue to true;
[breakpoint after that line is executed, you can set yieldValue to false here]
if yieldValue, yield value;

in other words:

bool yieldValue = true;
[breakpoint here]
if(yieldValue) yield value;
```

Note that you usually can't stick a breakpoint on an empty line.  You'll have to stick it before the if statement, though.

Answer (score -2):

In debuggers, generally you want to "step" (s) into a function in this case, rather than "next" (n).

"Next" executes the next line in the scope you're looking at; "step" brings you into the next scope down, the generator in this case, which sounds like what you want to do.

Comment: No, he's saying that *within the generator*, he wants to step over a yield and land on the line following it, which is exactly what "next" should be doing.  ("1 comment per 15 seconds, timer reset"?  Ugh, whoever thought that was a good idea needs to be shot...)